# How can I find files that end in ".html", but don't have ".bin" anywhere in the filename?

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find, filenames

I have the following types of file names:

1. One ends with `.html`:

   ```
   l_scheduling_suite.temp.html
   ```
2. Another type ends with `.html` but has `.bin` in its name:

   ```
   l_scheduling_suite.temp.bin.html
   ```
3. And a third ends with `.bin`:

   ```
   l_scheduling_suite.temp.bin
   ```

The filename is arbitrary. It won't necessarily always have a `temp` before `.html` or `.bin`. I need to find all the files that comply with only the first format. I am piping to grep using the following regex to find the files, but I am not able to make it work:

```
"(?=(\.html)$) (?=(?!\.bin))"
```

How should I use grep or find to get the right list of files?

Comment: So, basically you want to find files that ends in `.temp.html` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find -type f | grep -P '^.*(?<!\.bin)\.html$'
```

This uses a negative lookbehind. Basically it means, get all names that end with `.html`, but then just make sure that `.bin` doesn't come before it.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Simple Glob Pattern

You're vastly overcomplicating the problem. All you need (based on your posted corpus) is:

```
find . -name \*.temp.html
```

This will find all files that *end* with `.temp.html`. Your other examples wouldn't match because `*.bin.html` and `*.temp.bin` have no overlap with this glob pattern.

### Use Negated Globs

If your corpus was poorly chosen, and you're actually trying to match all files that *end* in `.html` but that *don't* include `.bin` anywhere in the name, then you can just use the find utility with a negated glob without resorting to regular expressions, pipes, extended shell globs, or other contortions. For example:

```
find . -name '*.html' -not -name '*.bin*'
```

Comment: He gave examples, but the problem definition didn't say anything about `.temp`. (Also, see his edit).